# GLPI Tickets workflow

Tags: glpi

I hope you're all doing well.
I'm currently working on setting up a workflow in GLPI, and I could use some guidance on configuring a specific rule. Here's what I'm aiming to achieve:

Scenario:

-User1 create a ticket.
-an approval request sent to a manager.
-Once the manager approves the ticket, it should be automatically assigned to a technician.

please any one can help me or  explain to me how approve process work.

thanks in advance